# getline not working with opening a file

Tags: c++, algorithm, fstream, getline

I am opening a file and searching for a keyword in a line.
If that keyword is found,I keep on reading lines from file till again I found that same keyword in the file.It is working in most of the cases.But in one case,It is not working correctly.This line

```
  ::MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("here -2"), TEXT(""), MB_OK);
```

is never getting executed when i checked. I assume find function never have a success in finding.I am doubting getline() function. The text I am looking exists in the file and it is string with spaces[Like "AB CD EF"].It exists as the very first pattern on the line and line has no spaces before this text.Can Anyone suggest what mistake I am doing.I am new in C++. Here is my code.

```
std::ifstream in(curr_file_path);
std::string search("SEARCH");
std::string line;

char *pDestText = new char[8000*256+1];
int f_match = -1;
int l_match = -1;
int r_val=0;
int textLen = 0;
int flag = 0;
  while (std::getline(in, line))
    {

        r_val = line.find(search);
        if (r_val!=(std::string::npos))
        {
            ::MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("here -2"), TEXT(""), MB_OK);
            f_match = r_val;

            while (std::getline(in, line))
            {
                ::MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("here -3"), TEXT(""), MB_OK);
                r_val = line.find(search);
                if (r_val != std::string::npos)
                {
                    l_match = r_val;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    ::MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("here -4"), TEXT(""), MB_OK);
                    for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
                    {
                        pDestText[textLen++] = line[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            ::MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("here -5"), TEXT(""), MB_OK);
            for (int i = 0; i < r_val; i++)
            {
                //if(line[i]!='=')
                ::MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("here -6"), TEXT(""), MB_OK);
                pDestText[textLen++] = line[i];
            }
            //pDestText[textLen] = '\0';
            ::MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("here -7"), TEXT(""), MB_OK);
            break;
        }
    }
    in.close();
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, as it read and parsed the file, easily examining the values of all variables shown here, on each step of the way, what observations did you make when the code in question read the line containing your search string? There's no reason to sit and wait for someone on stackoverflow.com to figure it out for you, when you could've figured it out yourself in five minutes. You should really learn how to use a debugger. Knowing how to use a debugger is a mandatory skill for every C++ developer. This is what it's there for.

Comment: Sam is 100% correct! And if you don't have/use a debugger, at least use some debug prints, for example: you say you thing `getline` won't work, put a `std::cout << line << std::endl` after it to see what it reads...

Answer (score 0):

I like to show people standard C++, in clean ways¹.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7f1e418f0ac2cb9)</kbd>**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

// start SEARCH block

bool filter_lines(std::istream& haystack, std::string const& needle, std::ostream& dest) {
    bool active = false;
    std::string line;

    auto trigger = [&] { 
        bool match = std::string::npos != line.find(needle); 
        if (match)
            active = !active;
        return match;
    };

    auto act = [&] { if (active) dest << line << "\n"; };

    while (getline(haystack, line))
        if (!trigger())
            act();

    return active;
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream ifs("main.cpp");
    std::stringstream destText;

    if (filter_lines(ifs, "SEARCH", destText)) 
        std::cerr << "Warning: last delimited block unclosed\n";

    std::cout << "------------- FILTERED -----------\n" 
              << destText.rdbuf() 
              << "----------------------------------\n";
}
```

¹ I realize I may not address the exact question, but I feel this type of answer is often more beneficial. The same goes for the constructive comments to use the debugger to find your own mistakes